# Ideas for 1" of ceiling/crown trim?

Tags: drywall, windows, trim

I'm drywalling around a window.  The window has a 12" deep "frame", which I plan to drywall on the sides and the top, and then make a wooden sill on the bottom.  The problem is that the top of the frame's framing is about .5" below the room's finished ceiling.  When the "ceiling" of the window frame gets drywalled, it will be about 1" below the room's ceiling.

The question is - how do I make this 1" "drop" look good? I could just cut a really narrow piece of drywall, but I feel like having a 1" 90 degree "step" at the top of the window will look kind of tacky.  I've thought about adding a bull nose bead, but it might be a really snug fit and tough to attach the top side of it.  I've also looked at various molding at my hardware store, but none of it is as narrow as 1" - most of it starts at around 2-2.5" wide.

Any ideas?
[image: close up of top of window framing]

[image: window zoomed out]

Comment: I think trim would draw more attention to it, especially if the trim is only in front of the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut out the plate at the wall. let the drywall run up to the window and add a minor piece of wood, something like lattice to cover the difference at the edge of the window to the new ceiling extension. It may take 2 pieces to form a new corner at the window, but I think the corner would be better at the window rather than at the wall face.

Comment: Good idea! A bit more work but a cleaner look. Top plate might be tough to rip out at this point though...

Comment: Should not be, a reciprocating saw will make quick work of it with a cut on either end flush with the corner at the window opening, and another in the middle to make it easier to pop out. Even a multi-tool will do it with a little more time to cut, since it cuts slower. Even a hand saw is an option.